# Mantener una variable POST en un URL

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en un sistema online que no requiere conocimientos de programación (justo para mi) y una de las opciones que tiene para crear un contenido es un plugin llamado *Mobile*, donde podés pegar la dirección de cualquier página web para que se muestre dentro de la aplicación.

Lo siguiente es el código que genera ese plugin *Mobile*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BlankTemplate7771</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function()
        {
            var url, hdiv = document.getElementById("hiddendivid");

            if (hdiv != null)
                url = hdiv.innerText || hdiv.textContent;

            if (url)
            {
                if (top == self)
                    window.location = url;
                else
                    top.updateWindowWithContentsOfUrl(self, url);
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="hiddendivid" style="display:none">http://devocionmusical.com</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Como ven, la dirección web que yo le di es http://devocionmusical.com

Lo que quiero saber es, si puedo agregar esto "*/fromMyApp=true*" al final de la ruta.

Quizás me sugieran que le agregue manualmente esa variable al url, pero el problema es que si el usuario va a otra seccion de la web devocionmusical.com, entonces esa variable desaparece.

¿Hay forma de hacer que **/fromMyApp=true** se mantenga siempre aunque el usuario vaya a otra sección de la web?

Veo que usa *JavaScript* al principio, por eso mi duda de saber si se puede o no hacerlo con ese lenguaje.

Comment: Todo depende de lo que quieras. Con jQuery puedes incluso actualizar la página del usuario sin cambiar a otra página. Te preguntaría ¿para qué quieres guardar la variable, para usarla más tarde? Como con jQuery puedes enviar en cualquier momento lo que quieras al servidor no veo la utilidad de guardarla... puedes enfocar tu página de forma que esté siempre en el mismo sitio y que si el usuario necesita algún dato se lo pidas al servidor haciendo `post` o `get`a través de jQuery. Si de todos modos quieres conservarla y cambiar de página quizá sería mejor tenerla almacenada en una base de datos.

Comment: Este plugin te permite cargar la página de un tercero insertándola en un iframe? Tienes control sobre la página `devocionmusical`?

Comment: @amenadiel asi es, eso es exactamente lo que me permite hacer. Y si, tengo el control de la pagina web devocionmusical

Comment: @A.Cedano no entiendo casi nada de lo que me explicaste jaja, pero gracias igual. Lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario navegue la web (dentro de la app) desde este URL `devocionmusical.com/fromMyApp=true`  y que al ir a otra sección, esta variable _fromMyApp=true_ no desaparezca. Es decir, que el url sea `devocionmusical.com/songs/fromMyApp=true`

Comment: _Todo depende de lo que quieras. Con jQuery puedes incluso actualizar la página del usuario sin cambiar a otra página._ O sea, usando jQuery puedes hacer cualquier actualización de la página sin cambiar de url. Pero necesitarías un archivo php a través del cual actualizas el contenido enviando peticiones al servidor.

Comment: La variable la estarias pasando por GET en ves de post, segun lo que entiendo por lo que esta mal formulado el titulo

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres almacenar una variable durante la seccion puedes utilizar **window.localStorage** o **window.sessionStorage** y no agregarlas a la ruta url son fáciles de definir y trabajar con ellas ya que funcionan como un diccionario y puedes almacenar estructuras completas en formato JSON solo tienen la limitación de 10Mb de tamaño maximo pero de todos modos tenes tamaño de sobra. Y el extra de mantener urls limpias.

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('fromMyApp', true);
let valor = window.sessionStorage.getItem('fromMyApp')
```

la unica diferencia entre seccionStorage y localStorage, es que la primera desaparecen los datos cuando cierras el navegador, mientras que la segunda persisten hasta que llames a `.clear()` o borres los datos de navegacion.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias @Ricardo, parece muy util, pero la verdad no entiendo nada porque al no ser programador se me complica. Voy a ver si tengo tiempo de investigar un poco mas sobre esto. Muchas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: En termino simple es un almacen clave valor, es muy util si quieres pasar los parametros dentro de la URL por GET deberas colocarlo en cada enlace lo que lo hace mas engorroso, ni hablar la parte de recuperar los datos. Puedes ver mas acerca de [WebStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API), es bastante sencillo y util. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que te entiendo, para que se te conserve la URL es colocando, luego de la URL, el símbolo "?"

Te quedaría asi:

```
"http://devocionmusical.com?fromMyApp=true"
```

Pero si navegas dentro del `iframe` no podrás modificar los enlaces.

Comment: Gracias @andrwsv pero no funcionó, porque si el usuario navega a la seccion devocionmusical.com/songs la parte _fromMyApp=true_ desaparece automaticamente. Sigo en la misma situación.